# With the new rulings is It That Betrays able to take an enemy's Commander?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I've been looking it up and back in 2016 it said that you can't because when it goes to the graveyard the player can change it to go to the command zone, and because they change where it goes it can't be taken from [It That Betrays](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=It%20That%20Betrays).

But I've looked it up the new rules, and it says that commanders now go to the graveyards and then if they're found in the graveyard they can be put back into the command zone, because they changed it so that commanders can now be used as death triggers.

Answer (score 3):

### It That Betrays cannot steal an enemy commander.

The short version is that the commanders don't move to the command zone using a normal triggered effect, they instead use a state-based action.  State based actions are fast - the commander has already left the graveyard by the time any regular triggered actions like the one It That Betrays has resolve.

Comment: I did hear that it can happen as long as there's an enchantment like Wheel of Sun and Moon on it saying when sacrificed it goes through the commander zone. Is that true?

Comment: Comments are not for asking additional questions.

Comment: Technically, It The Betrays can steal an enemy commander, if its owner doesn't exercise their option to move it to the command zone. If you Mindslave an opponent, then you have them "choose" to waive the option.

Comment: It The Betrays will also steal a commander that would not have ended up in the graveyard or exile, like Progenitus

Answer (score 2):

Under the current rule **903.9** [It That Betrays](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=It%20That%20Betrays) *can't* steal a commander that has returned to the command zone *via the graveyard or exile*.

The updated rules mean that commanders will enter the graveyard or exile first, and then move to the command zone via a state-based action.
This movement creates a new game object, causing *It That Betrays* to lose track of the card.

If however a replacement effect would mean that the commander would be placed into its owner’s hand or library instead (e.g. [Wheel of Sun and Moon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wheel%20of%20Sun%20and%20Moon), or [Progenitus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Progenitus)), and the owner chooses to use **903.9b** to put the commander in the command zone instead, then *It That Betrays* will track the card to its ultimate destination and steal it.
This is enabled by **400.7e** which allows *It That Betrays* to find the new object if the target zone is public.

With the original destination on the left and location while *It That Betrays'* ability resolves across the top, this table should clarify things:

|  | Command Zone | Graveyard/Exile/Library/Hand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Graveyard/Exile** | Remains in Command Zone | Returned to *Battlefield* |
| **Library/Hand** | Returned to *Battlefield* | Remains in Library/Hand |

---

**Rules**

> **903.9.** A commander may return to the command zone during a Commander game.
>
> **903.9a** If a commander is in a graveyard or in exile and that object was put into that zone since the last time state-based actions were checked, its owner may put it into the command zone. This is a state-based action. See rule **704**.
>
> **903.9b** If a commander would be put into its owner’s hand or library from anywhere, its owner may put it into the command zone instead. This replacement effect may apply more than once to the same event. This is an exception to rule **614.5**.
>
> **400.7e** Abilities that trigger when an object moves from one zone to another (for example, "When Rancor is put into a graveyard from the battlefield") can find the new object that it became in the zone it moved to when the ability triggered, if that zone is a public zone.

Answer (score 0):

### It can, but...

Only if the owner of the commander choses to not move it back to the command zone.  As other people have pointed out:

> 903.9a If a commander is in a graveyard or in exile and that object was put into that zone since the last time state-based actions were checked, its owner **may** put it into the command zone. This is a state-based action.

Most of the time, the owner will chose to put it back into the command zone.  If they do, you would not be able to pick it up with It That Betrays, even if you flash it in.  However, there are cases where it is advantageous to leave your commander in the graveyard (you have a resurrect ability, you're playing Haakon, etc).  If the commander is left in the graveyard, then you can pick it up with ITB.

Comment: It That Betrays will also steal commanders with replacement effects that direct them to a hand or library.